# Installing MySQL and checking root password fails?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I recently uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL (on Windows 7) using the installer. When I try to set up the MySQL Server, it won't let me continue unless I enter the "current" root password??? I don't understand how there can be a current root password if I completely uninstalled and reinstalled the program.

I've tried with a blank password as well as every password I can possibly think of that I would have used and nothing works. Google is completely unhelpful as every result I've found either refers to a "homebrew" installation, whatever that is, or refers to installations on Linux. Is there some folder of config files that the uninstallation refuses to delete that I need to remove manually? Or am I missing something else?

[image: image of problem because SO won't let you have pictures until you're popular]

Comment: how did you uninstalled it?

Comment: @Simonare Using the MySQL installer, I had hoped that that would be a more thorough uninstallation than using the Windows Add and Remove Programs but evidently not...

Comment: The DB data is not removed by the installer, since it might contain valuable data. You have to remove it manually. And this DB data includes your user credentials.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After uninstallation process, please check following directories if it exists and remove:

- C:\Program Files\MySQL
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL
- C:\ProgramData\MySQL
- C:\Users[User-Name]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL

PS: Please keep in mind that If you have multiple MySql Instances installed on your workstation, you need to go into each directory and delete only the relevant instance.

Comment: Dangerous advice. With that the user might remove more than what's intended (e.g. if more than one server was installed). Instead the user should specifically look for the version (s)he wants to uninstall and only remove the data for that version (and the same architecture (x86, x64) for that matter.

Comment: @MikeLischke, sometimes the best thing to do is to get rid of all it start from ground zero.

Comment: I think the db data itself is likely located in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\data`

Comment: This worked for my use case in 2023. Hadn't used in a while so uninstalled to save memory, new use case for mysql came up, couldn't remember root password and couldn't install mysql without it. Nuked it all as this answer suggests, got a fresh install working.

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the same issue but the following worked for me:
Go to Control **Panel >> Programs >> Programs and Features**, select MySQL Server  and click Uninstall.
Also uninstall the MySQL workbench, MySQL Installer Community, MySQL Router.
Then delete the files:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL
C:\ProgramData\MySQL
C:\Users\[User-Name]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL
```

Finally restart your system and install MySQL again.

Comment: I used the installer to uninstall. Then it removed the root user too.

Answer (score 2):

In a fresh development machine, after installing MySQl 8.0.18 in Windows 10 64 bit, I hit this error and could not connect to MySql.
Nothing else worked.
Then I uninstalled the Mysql and deleted C:\Program Files\MySQL and retried installing MySql 8.0.18 and while re-installing it asked to specify root user password. 
After specifying the root password, I was able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem, i tried the same process and this works for me too. Also i uninstalled my MySQL installer, MySQL shell, MySQL workbench, MySQL server and all connectors and routers from my Control Panel>>Uninstall a program and after deleting everything. I tried this solution install MySQL again from the oracle website and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

when I was facing the same issue, I used "password" for root password, which is default for MySql.