# Error installing MySQL 8.0.20 (Windows 10) when entering current root password

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, change-password

I am trying to install the new version MySQL 8.0.20 through the downloaded pack "mysql-installer-community-8.0.20.0".

I got stuck in the step "Accounts and Roles". I have entered the "Current root password" that I had from the past, but now it does not work. But I am totally sure this password is correct.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw36v.png)

I have tried to unnistall MySQL from the Control Panel and delete each windows folder and file related to MySQL (even I can't find anything related to MySQL when opening the application "Services" from Windows 10), and re-install it again. But such password does not work.

Maybe, another solution would be to reset the password? But I have tried to go the "MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client" to do that but I can't open such black window to type the right code to change the password, such window does not pop up.

***Just in case it helps, I point out 3 facts: 
1) Before installing "mysql-installer-community-8.0.20.0", I had installed a previous version of MySQL through the pack "mysql-installer-web-community" (web version). But I unnistalled such version before installing the new one.

2) Yesterday, I tried to configure such MySQL 8.0.20 through the downloaded pack "mysql-installer-community-8.0.20.0", and my password was rightly accepted. However, such configuration process got stuck in the step "Apply Configuration". It got stuck in the step " Starting the server", pointing out that "The configuration step is taking longer than expected". And it never ended. That is why today I tried to do it again, but now the process is stuck in the previous password step. Very strange.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKkLt.png)

3) And another point that could help is that when I installed such previous version, I configured it selecting in the step "Authentication Method" the second option (Use legacy Authentication Method (Retain MySQL 5.x Compatibility).

Any help would be great. Thank you very much in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DLJ !

Not sure if you still have this problem, but, nevertheless, whoever finds your question may still have some use of the following example cases:

1. [Installing MySQL and checking root password fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54428037/installing-mysql-and-checking-root-password-fails)
2. [Setting up new instance of MySQL what is Current Root Password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222341/setting-up-new-instance-of-mysql-what-is-current-root-password)

I have also encountered that root account password request issue. I have:

1. uninstalled everything from Control Panel regarding MySQL;
2. restarted my computer to get rid of any rights issue against C drive location (where I had MySQL installed);
3. deleted all the following paths related to MySQL: C:\Program Files\MySQL
   C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL
   C:\ProgramData\MySQL
   C:\Users[User-Name]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL
4. ran again installer community and seems that "Accounts and Roles" no longer request from you an existing password to check, but a new one :)